# Display an image on the page if equals specific text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 different text values inside a class of line_item mrimachinetype

my two options will be
Open MRI
or 
Closed Bore High Field.

edit:  Can now use HTML, CSS and now JS as well to accomplish this.

How can I have image A show on the page when it says Open MRI and image B show for Closed Bore High Field ?

```
<span class="line_item mrimachinetype">Closed Bore High Field</span>

or <span class="line_item mrimachinetype">Open MRI</span>
```

Comment: You mean it's controlled by click?

Comment: Without JavaScript it’s currently impossible to style an element based on text; if the text is, or is also, stored in an attribute of the element then it may be possible with css. But that depends entirely upon your markup and where the image is that you wish to show. Can you show your relevant “*[mcve]*” code, along with your own efforts to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is my solution :**

I used div element to determine what content currently needs to be shown. Here is a codepen so that you could try this [link](https://codepen.io/rei-marco/pen/mdymgvb).

I hope this helps.

```css
/** FOR IMAGE **/

/* Hide image with data-content "Open MRI" value */
div[data-content="Closed Bore High Field"] img[data-content="Open MRI"] {
    display:none;
}

/* Hide image with data-content "Closed Bore High Field" value */
div[data-content="Open MRI"] img[data-content="Closed Bore High Field"] {
    display:none;
}

/** FOR SPAN **/

/* Hide span with data-content "Open MRI" value */
div[data-content="Closed Bore High Field"] span[data-content="Open MRI"] {
    display:none;
}

/* Hide span with data-content "Closed Bore High Field" value */
div[data-content="Open MRI"] span[data-content="Closed Bore High Field"] {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<!-- 
Change this data-content value to what item you want to show 
OPTIONS: 
  Open MRI
  Closed Bore High Field
-->
<div data-content="Closed Bore High Field">

  <span data-content="Closed Bore High Field" class="line_item mrimachinetype">Closed Bore High Field</span>
<br>
  <img data-content="Closed Bore High Field" src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/aquir/aquir1311/aquir131100316/23569861-sample-grunge-red-round-stamp.jpg" style="width:200px;height:200px;"/>
  
  <span data-content="Open MRI" class="line_item mrimachinetype">Open MRI</span>
<br>
  <img data-content="Open MRI" src="https://smaller-pictures.appspot.com/images/dreamstime_xxl_65780868_small.jpg" style="width:200px;height:200px;"/>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't without using javascript or altering the HTML, since CSS doesn't currently recognize text content. The most unobtrusive way you can achieve this is by using data-attributes:

```css
body{display: flex; justify-content: space-around}

.line_item[data-content="Closed Bore High Field"]::before,
.line_item[data-content="Open MRI"]::before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.line_item[data-content="Closed Bore High Field"]::before{
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/200/200)
}

.line_item[data-content="Open MRI"]::before{
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/220/220)
}
```

```html
<span data-content="Closed Bore High Field" class="line_item mrimachinetype">Closed Bore High Field</span>
<span data-content="Open MRI" class="line_item mrimachinetype">Open MRI</span>
```

### Update: In Javascript

```js
let lis = document.querySelectorAll(".line_item")

for(let i=0; i<lis.length; i++){
    if(lis[i].textContent === "Closed Bore High Field"){
        lis[i].classList += " CBHF"
    }else if(lis[i].textContent === "Open MRI"){
        lis[i].classList += " OMRI"
    }
}
```

```css
body{display: flex; justify-content: space-around}

.line_item{
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-position: 0 -1.4em;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}

.line_item.CBHF{
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/200/200)
}

.line_item.OMRI{
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/220/220)
}
```

```html
<span class="line_item mrimachinetype">Closed Bore High Field</span>
<span class="line_item mrimachinetype">Open MRI</span>
```

Comment: I was able to get them to allow me to run JS.  Would you be able to show me how I would do the same example with JS?  Thanks for the help btw